# How do I create a library in C?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I am working on a program that is using libgit2. I had kept the code in a single c file. Say:

somefile.c

I compile and use it. Now I want to separate some of the details related to libgit2 into a separate library inside the project. So I created an h file with the data structures that I need and the definitions of the functions I want to use. So far, nothing fancy: init stuff, pass in the path to the repo and s a treeish... those are const * constant.... then In the library c file I have an implementation of the functions in the .h file.

*Currently*, the layout is like this:

```
include/mylib.c
include/mylib.h
somefile.c
```

In `include/mylib.h` I have one struct and a couple of functions:

```
struct blah {} blah_info;

int blah_init(cont char * path, const char * treeish);

int blah_shutdown();
```

In include/mylib.c I include mylib.h:

```
#include "mylib.h" # notice that I don't have to use "include" in the path
```

And then I have definitions for the 2 functions that I put in the .h file.

In `somefile.c` now I am including the library **c** file, not the .h file (and no need to include git2.h anymore either as that is done in mylib files now).

```
#include "include/mylib.c"
```

And this allows me to compile and run the program, just like it did before I separated it into pieces *but* I know it's possible to include `include/mylib.h` from the original .c file. I think it requires to build the library before then going into compiling the final program? What steps are required for that?

Right now I'm compiling by hand in a shell script calling GCC in a single shot... so if I need to run more commands to do so, just let me know so that I add them to the script.

Comment: If you're `#include`ing a C file, something is wrong.

Comment: It's not technically impossible, say... it is working.... but I know it's not correct. That's why I'm making the question.

Comment: Even if it compiles, you should never `#include` a C file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `somefile.c`, you need to do this:

```
#include "include/mylib.h"
```

And make sure you ***define*** these functions in `mylib.c`:

```
int blah_init(cont char * path, const char * treeish) {

}

int blah_shutdown() {

}
```

And then ***declare*** them in `mylib.h`:

```
struct blah {} blah_info;

int blah_init(cont char * path, const char * treeish);

int blah_shutdown();
```

And when you compile, include both `somefile.c` and `mylib.c` as input files.

Comment: I know this is the right direction but it is incomplete. If I only do that, I get an error by ld: `somefile.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `blah_init'`.

Comment: @eftshift0 Define them in the C file, and declare them in the H file

Comment: checked, checked.

Comment: Are you including `mylib.c` as an input file when you compile it? `gcc somefile.c mylib.c -o output`

Comment: Oh, there you go. So I add it as another argument to gcc? Let me try that.

Comment: You got it! could you elaborate on how to do it creating a previous o (or so?) file for the library only and then use gcc using that file? Thanks!

Comment: @eftshift0 I don't know how to link already compiled o files to your C project, if that's what you mean, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Right! Voted it up and didn't check it.:-O

Comment: Also you should check with preprocessor if the header wasn't included somewhere else before, if you really want to use those files as library.

Answer (score 0):

#include directive is used to insert content of a file somewhere else and it's mostly used to include headers so compiler knows what is what (types, constants, etc), then linker puts all compiled files into one single executable.
to make sure header is included only once to a single file you use something called conditional compilation, it's done with preprocessor (before compilation)

yourlib.h

```
#ifndef YOUR_LIB_H_ //there are many naming conventions but I prefer this one
#define YOUR_LIB_H_

//all your declarations go here

#endif //YOUR_LIB_H_
//you should put in comment what's that condition for after every endif
```

now in yourlib.c you include that header and then write your definitions

```
#include "yourlib.h"

//all your definitions go here
```

and same thing for your main file, just include the header and compiler knows what to do

```
#include "yourlib.h"

//your code goes here
```